# Two Dropdown showing same list bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I want to show two dropdowns in the same line. That is a preheader.
Here is my code:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>verification" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Verification</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #000080;">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>verification/certificates">Verify Certificates</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>verification/membership">Verify Membership</a></li>

</ul>
<a class="nav-link2 dropdown-toggle" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>opportunities" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Opportunities</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #000080;">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link2" href="http://robotics.uiu.ac.bd/form/wanted_graphicdesigner">Graphic Designer Wanted</a></li>
</ul>
```

But here, 2nd dropdown is not working, showing the list of 1st dropdown,
I mean, in the 2nd dropdown, 'graphic designer wanted' should be shown, but instead of it, verification is showing.

Why it is happend? what is the listener key here, how should i give a unique id here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to separate the two dropdowns and put them in a `<div>` for example:

```
<div>
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>verification" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Verification</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #000080;">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>verification/certificates">Verify Certificates</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>verification/membership">Verify Membership</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="nav-link2 dropdown-toggle" href="<?php echo $baseurl;?>opportunities" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Opportunities</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #000080;">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link2" href="http://robotics.uiu.ac.bd/form/wanted_graphicdesigner">Graphic Designer Wanted</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```